# Hyperlinking to another image within Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have an Excel file here, and I am trying to click the display hyperlink to take me to a specific image in the other sheet, which is the "Definitions" tab. But it is only letting me reference a specific cell in a document. I have genuinely tried looking for a solution on my own but I have not been able to find one. I have a bunch of images in the "Definitions" Tab and I want to hyperlink to  a specific image. There is one image for each hyperlink.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can link to a cell where the picture is located. In this way you come to the right place when clicking the link.

Make a picture setting to move the picture with cells

[image]